# DirectX 9 загрузка модели

Tags: directx

Я создал модель в cinema4d или в другом 3d редакторе с движением,анимацией,спецэфектами, дополнительными объектами(со всем чем можно в 3d редакторе) и.т.д, в какой формат ее лучше экспортировать?

1.Можно в DirectX .x формат, но все ли экспортируется туда, качество и данные останутся теже что и в 3d редакторе, если да объясните, как вывести модель .x формата в DirectX 9 в программу(просто на рабочий стол) или покажите примеры пожалуйста

2.Или лучше в другой формат? Тогда в какой? И как вывести в программу(просто на рабочий стол)

Мне нужно вывести максимально качественную модель со всеми данными(с движением,анимацией,спецэфектами, дополнительными объектами(со всем чем можно в 3d редакторе, и.т.д)

Ответе кто знает пожалуйста попонятнее, без флуда, с примерами. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Если остановиться на "как вывести модель на рабочий стол со всеми спецэффектами и анимацией" - это слишком комплексная и сложная тема для поста на stackoverflow. Если вам нужно единожды вывести модель на экран со всем, что у вас есть - лучше воспользоваться готовым графическим или игровым движком, возможно, использовать рендер самого 3д редактора. Если вам нужно писать собственный 3д движок для рендера - нужно читать соответствующую литературу, правильный и полный ответ на ваш вопрос просто не поместится здесь.

Comment: Мне нужен собственный 3д движок для рендера, можете подскажите где взять книги, видеоуроки, и.т.д. именно для собственного 3д движка для рендера

Comment: И все же я настоятельно не рекомендую писать свой движок для рендеринга с нуля, но хозяин - барин.

Comment: подскажите где взять книги, видеоуроки, и.т.д. именно для собственного 3д движка для рендера

Answer (score 0):

Хоть вопрос и общий, приведу неплохие, *на мой скромный взгляд*, книги.

Сразу небольшой дисклеймер, "написать свой графический движок" - не консольное приложение собрать, это очень сложная и обширная тема. Писать с нуля что-то действительно серьезное и сложное равносильно самоубийству. Практически каждая книга по графике достаточно сложная и массивная, изучать такой огромный пласт только ради одного графического приложения с API будь то DirectX или OpenGL - пустая трата времени, гораздо проще и рациональнее взять уже готовый игровой/графический движок, благо в наши дни на них можно добиться очень красивой картинке даже в реальном времени.

---

**Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 12 (Frank Lua)** - основы основ, с нуля учат как работе с DirectX, так и математике, без которой выжить в мире графики невозможно. Эта книга является неким обобщенным разъяснением основ DirectX.

**Real-Time 3D Rendering with DirectX and HLSL: A Practical Guide to Graphics Programming (Paul Varcholik)** - по сути, аналог книги выше, но тут больший упор делается именно на шейдеры и, очевидно, язык шейдеров под DirectX - HLSL.

**Physically Based Rendering: From Theory to Implementation (Matt Pharr)** - если мы говорим про "красивую" 3D графику, без PBR не обойтись.

**Practical Rendering and Computation with Direct3D 11 (Jason Zink)** - более сложный материал по DirectX, нежели первые две книги, но много информации здесь повторяется, так что прочесть ее после вводной книги по данному API будет проще.

На этом, наверное, все. Полезных книг гораздо больше, но для ввода в мир графики и конкретно DirectX этого достаточно.

---

Отдельно про видео, я не советую изучать DirectX по видео просто потому что воспринимать информацию и такой код на слух и в формате видео довольно сложно, книги и отдельные статьи, по моему скромному мнению, лучше.

Comment: спасибр Physically Based Rendering: From Theory to Implementation (Matt Pharr) на русском есть или  другие книги по этой теме

Comment: вопрос выше!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Читать о таких топиках на русском практически нет смысла - лишний раз запутаетесь в терминах. Других тем о PBR я не встречал, на русском даже не искал. Если вам очень нужно найти русскую версию - гуглите, тут не поисковая площадка, а ответы на конкретные вопросы.

Comment: спасибо, тогда задам вопрос по книгам

Comment: А вы применяли эту технологию у себя в программах, извините если наглею, может есть ваши примеры или программы, которые не жалко

Comment: Я если и затрагиваю графику, то только шейдеры, данные книги я частично для этого и читал, так что ничем не могу помочь. Как я уже сказал, если вам нужно один раз воспользоваться графическим софтом - используйте готовые движки, возможно даже игровые. "игровые" не значит "плохие", в них есть тот или иной способ отрендерить нужную сцену в лучшем разрешении с лучшими эффектами, прямо как в программах для монтажа.